# SQL Connection Query to join multiple MS access Tables in crystal Report 9

Tags: ms-access, crystal-reports

I've working without any problem for below of SQL command linking

```
    SELECT `linkaccess`.`PLPON`, `taxaccess`.`crddate`, `taxaccess`.`duedate`, `supplierlist`.`Term`, `linkaccess`.`PLLINE`, `linkaccess`.`stkcode`, `linkaccess`.`stkdesc`, `linkaccess`.`psno`, `linkaccess`.`qty`
     FROM   `linkaccess` `linkaccess` 
INNER JOIN (`taxaccess` `taxaccess` INNER JOIN `supplierlist` `supplierlist` ON `supplierlist`.`SuppCode`=`taxaccess`.`SuppCode`) ON `linkaccess`.`PLPON`=`taxaccess`.`PLPON`
     ORDER BY `linkaccess`.`PLPON`
```

But I failed to load After I replace INNER join with left outer join command, Can someone correct me if know, I need to make left outer join to taxaccesss and then using inner join to join with supplierlist wth fields suppcode. Appreciate thanks to any kindful help.

Error Meesages:

```
"Failed to open a rowset. 
Details: ADO Error Code : 0x80040e14 
Source: Microsoft Office Access Database Engine
Description: JOIN expression not supported.
SQL State: 3000
Native Code: -540806602"

SELECT `linkaccess`.`PLPON`, `taxaccess`.`crddate`, `taxaccess`.`duedate`, `supplierlist`.`Term`, `linkaccess`.`PLLINE`, `linkaccess`.`stkcode`, `linkaccess`.`stkdesc`, `linkaccess`.`psno`, `linkaccess`.`qty`
 FROM   `linkaccess` `linkaccess` LEFT OUTER JOIN (`taxaccess` `taxaccess` INNER JOIN `supplierlist` `supplierlist` ON `supplierlist`.`SuppCode`=`taxaccess`.`SuppCode`) ON `linkaccess`.`PLPON`=`taxaccess`.`PLPON`
 ORDER BY `linkaccess`.`PLPON`
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have to different joins going out from the same table. What you can do is run the first join and then run the results against the other table using the INNER JOIN